# Getting response by invoking a Servlet from a linux shell script

Tags: linux, shell, servlets

There is a requirement where I am currently invoking a Servlet from a shell script using wget command. The servlet performs the job of generating a report and sends an email to a list of users.

As I am planning to schedule this job, I would like to find out if the Servlet completed successfully or not. If there are any exceptions thrown from the Servlet, I would like to find that out from the shell script and thereby mark the job as Success or Failure.

Can someone provide a solution for this...?

Answer (score 0):

The servlet should reply with a 500 Internal Server Error status code if there is an unhandled exception. Check if wget permits identifying the http response status code in some way.

Comment: Server 500 error gets thrown only if the wget command itself does not succeed. For instance, if the servlet being invoked is not running.

However, if there any application related handled or unhanled exceptions, I would need to find if the job ran successfully without any handled or un-handled exceptions. So, using HTTP response code might not satisfy the entire requirement